# Statsmodels Python Predict Linear Regression with one less predictor

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, predict

I have trained a linear regression model with 20 predictors over a year long dataset. Below is x20 which is a list of arrays, each array is a predictor to be fed into the linear regression. y is the observations that I am fitting to, and model is the resulting linear regression model. The observations and predictors are being selected over a training period (all except for the last day (24 hours) which I will verify or predict over):

```
num_verifydays = 1
##############Train MOS model##################
x20=[predictor1[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor2[:-(num_verifydays)*24],
predictor3[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor4[:-(num_verifydays)*24],
predictor5[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor6[:-(num_verifydays)*24],
predictor7[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor8[:-(num_verifydays)*24],
predictor9[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor10[:-(num_verifydays)*24],
predictor11[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor12[:-(num_verifydays)*24],
predictor13[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor14[:-(num_verifydays)*24],
predictor15[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor16[:-(num_verifydays)*24],
predictor17[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor18[:-(num_verifydays)*24],
predictor19[:-(num_verifydays)*24],predictor20[:-(num_verifydays)*24]]

x20 = np.asarray(x20).T.tolist()

y = result_full['obs'][:-(num_verifydays)*24]

model = sm.OLS(y,x20, missing='drop').fit()
```

I want to predict using this model over my verification day using all 20 predictors and then just using 19 predictors to see how much of a difference there is in skill when using less predictors. I tried setting predictor20 to an array of zeros in x19 which you will see below but that seems to give me weird results:

```
##################predict with regression model##################
x20=[predictor1[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor2[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor3[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor4[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor5[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor6[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor7[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor8[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor9[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor10[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor11[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor12[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor13[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor14[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor15[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor16[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor17[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor18[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor19[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor20[-(num_verifydays)*24:]]

x19=[predictor1[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor2[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor3[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor4[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor5[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor6[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor7[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor8[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor9[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor10[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor11[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor12[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor13[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor14[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor15[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor16[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor17[-(num_verifydays)*24:],predictor18[-(num_verifydays)*24:],
predictor19[-(num_verifydays)*24:],np.zeros(num_verifydays*24)]

x20 = np.asarray(x20).T.tolist()
x19 = np.asarray(x19).T.tolist()

results20 = model.predict(x20)
results19 = model.predict(x19)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fit two different models, one with 19 exogenous variables and the other with 20.  This is much statistically sounder than testing the 20-variable model on the 19-variable set, because the fitted coefficients will be different.

```
model19 = sm.OLS(y,x19, missing='drop').fit()
model20 = sm.OLS(y,x20, missing='drop').fit()
```

What's the frequency of your data?  Using a test data set of 1 day (n=1) isn't going to get you a very true picture of variable importance.

Other ways to look at the importance of this variable would be to look at the incremental R-squared added or lost between the two models.

Also consider checking out `sklearn`'s [`feature_selection`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) capabilities.

Comment: My data is hourly. I am training the model over 364 days and then just testing my code by predicting for 1 day (the 365th day) I will be using a longer training period and verification period later. Basically I have a screening regression code seperate from this that chooses from a very large list of potential predictors and chooses the best 20 based on the R-squared adjusted values. So I am using those 20 predictors and then getting rid of the last one. I will try it this way and see! Thanks!

Comment: At hourly frequency, then that choice of sample makes a lot more sense.